# phantomJS on docker containers

Tags: phantomjs, docker, dokku

I am having a few issues with adding PhantomJS to our website docker containers.

I got 2 containers test and production but have no idea how to add it to each of these containers.

The containers are made with Dokku and are already running. This is a bit different so we are not able to pull up fresh containers with images or edit their Dockerfiles

Additionally we have managed to use commands like `wget` in them using `dokku run`, but this is not an interactive shell. Also the files downloaded with wget don't appear to be in the container when checking with `ls` even though the download finishes.

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/161559

Answer (score 13):

I would add to the Dockerfile something like:

```
# PhantomJS
ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION 1.9.7
RUN wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 | tar xjC /opt
RUN ln -s /opt/phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

Comment: +1 This also works for running Selenium-based tests inside a Debian-based Docker container (as opposed to the standard Debian package for PhantomJS which is broken)